# How list item is checked of checkedboxlist when it is fetch from database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

How `CheckedBoxListItem` is auto checked when it is fetch from database?

I have try this but get the following error:

> input string are not in correct format

```
private void MyTodo_Project_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conec"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd3;
    string sql3 = " SELECT Task From Todaywork where Username='" + Login.recuser + "' and Active='1'";
    try
    {
        con3.Open();
        cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, con3);
        string index = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cmd3.Dispose();
        con3.Close();

        checkedListBoxongoing.SelectedItem = index;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use string concatenation to make sql queries! Use parameters instead.